# Formulário para edição não exibe os dados carregados

Tags: php, codeigniter, sql-update

Estou tentando há algum tempo fazer um formulário em CodeIgniter 3 para edição de dados exibir em seus campos os valores de cada coluna do registro selecionado. A operação `update` está funcionando normalmente, porém como os campos vem em branco, preciso digitar tudo novamente.

Abaixo o meu modelo `MY_Model.php`:

```
<?php

class MY_Model extends CI_Model
{
    public $table = '';
    protected $primary_key = 'id';

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->load->database();
        $this->load->helper('inflector');
    }

    public function get($id)
    {
        return $this->db->get_where($this->table, array($this->primary_key = $id))->row();
    }

    public function select()
    {
        $data = array();

        $this->db->from($this->table);
        $this->db->order_by($this->primary_key, 'DESC');
        $query = $this->db->get();

        foreach ($query->result_array() as $row) {
            $data[] = $row;
        }

        $query->free_result();

        return $data;
    }

    public function insert($data)
    {
        $data['date_created'] = $data['date_updated'] = date('Y-m-d');
        $data['created_from_ip'] = $data['updated_from_ip'] = $this->input->ip_address();

        if ($this->db->insert($this->table, $data)) {
            return $this->db->insert_id();
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public function update($data, $id)
    {
        $data['date_updated'] = date('Y-m-d');
        $data['updated_from_ip'] = $this->input->ip_address();

        $this->db->where($this->primary_key, $id);

        return $this->db->update($this->table, $data);
    }

    public function delete($id)
    {
        $this->db->where($this->primary_key, $id);

        return $this->db->delete($this->table);
    }

    public function count_all()
    {
        return $this->db->count_all($this->table);
    }
}
```

Aqui a função `edit` do controle `Customers`:

```
public function edit($id)
{
    if ($this->input->post()) {
        $data['name'] = $this->input->post('name');
        $data['email'] = $this->input->post('email');
        $data['address'] = $this->input->post('address');

        $this->Customers_model->update($data, $id);
        $this->session->set_flashdata('message', 'Cliente \'' . $data['name'] . '\' alterado');

        redirect('/admin/customers', 'refresh');
    }

    $data['customer'] = $this->Customers_model->get($id);
    $data['page'] = $this->config->item('admin_template_dir_admin') . 'edit_customers';
    $data['module'] = 'admin';

    $this->load->view($this->_container, $data);
}
```

Já tentei muita coisa para exibir os dados para edição. Do modo que está agora, fazendo um `var_dump($customer)` apenas mostra `NULL`. Como proceder?

Comment: Se tela de update fica com os campos em branco, é sinal que o select deu errado ou não retornou nada daquele id.

Comment: Solucionei. Faltava um '>' na função `get` do `MY_Model`

Comment: Cria uma resposta :)

Comment: Pronto! Parece bruncadeira.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A função `get()` está com um `>` faltando.

```
return $this->db->get_where($this->table, array($this->primary_key = $id))->row();
```

Fica assim

```
return $this->db->get_where($this->table, array($this->primary_key => $id))->row();
```

Mal dá para acreditar.